# Separating strings and retrieving. using spaces

Tags: sql

The string contains many words separated by spaces e.g.

```
employee_first_nm = "John Walker"
```

I want to retrieve the first part alone ("John"). this part I have done using the following code:

```
SUBSTR(employee_first_nm, 1, INSTR(employee_first_nm, ' '));
```

In some cases the string has only one word e.g. "sonia", this is where I got a problem. Here if there is only one word the function doesn't retrieve any value at all. But I want it to get the full string in this case i.e. "sonia".

Please help

Comment: What RDBMS?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Something else?

Comment: If you're literally working with names and not just using them as an example, you need to read "[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)" to help avoid massive problems.

Answer (score 4):

Simply ensure there always *will* be a space;

```
... INSTR(employee_first_nm + ' ', ' ')
```

If there is already a space in the string then stuffing another one on the end makes no difference as the 1st one will be found, if there is no existing space adding one makes your logic work.

(Usually you also need to `INSTR(..)-1` to strip the trailing space)

Answer (score 1):

```
SUBSTR(employee_first_nm, 1, INSTR(CONCAT(employee_first_nm,' '), ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could check that INSTR returns a correct value:

```
(case when INSTR(employee_first_nm, ' ') > 0
      then SUBSTR(employee_first_nm, 1, INSTR(employee_first_nm, ' '))
      else employee_first_nm
 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not harness the power of regular expressions here.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(employee_first_nm, '^[a-zA-Z]*\s?')
```

This should return the substring you desire.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
SUBSTRING(select employee_first_nm,0, charindex(' ',employee_first_nm)
```

Tested with:

```
select substring('John walker',0, charindex(' ','John walker more'))
```

returns -> 'John'

Comment: -1 - Op already did this (using an Oracle function instead of charindex), the problem is when there is no space